# ASP.Net core template with JWT, Facebook, Microsoft, Gmail enabled

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have been looking for an ASP.Net core project template JWT based authentication and has support for Facebook, Microsoft and Google authentication.

Anyone know of a solid example/template that has all the above already implemented that we can just port across to new/existing projects?

Thanks
Kayes

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm looking for the same, preferably not something that is dependent on EF.